# JQuery, getting value of checked radio button, why is this not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am trying like below to get the value of a checked radio button but it just keeps giving undefined. I am using Firefox on Ubuntu so I don't know if its some weird quirk of the browser or what, I would appreciate any advice as this is driving me crazy:

```
            <input name="tagRow_ddd" type="radio" value="p">
                <input name="tagRow_ddd" type="radio" value="r">


alert($('input[name=tagRow_ddd]:checked').val())
```

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fD7fP/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's exactly the output it should give. the `:checked` selector only finds checked elements... you haven't any.

http://jsfiddle.net/fD7fP/7/

Answer (score 0):

Because by default nothing is checked.
If you have either checked by default it works.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/fD7fP/8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the attribute value
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

So it should be

```
alert($("input[name='tagRow_ddd']:checked").val())
```

Answer (score -1):

Try making one selected by default. Lke so

```
<input name="tagRow_ddd" type="radio" value="p">
<input name="tagRow_ddd" type="radio" value="r">
```

Comment: like so? you didn't check anything either.